# How do I keep passwords in my database encrypted and then immediately decrypt them in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, encryption

I wrote a Python script that compares a user input to database queries, then either allows a login or doesn't. I will break down my problem so that it is easier to understand:

1. My database has the passwords automatically encrypted for security reasons.
2. The script queries the database and then the encrypted password is stored in Python
3. If the correct password that the user has to type in in order to login is encrypted, and the user has to type in a normal (unencrypted) password, how do I then decrypt the password inside Python?

**Clarifications:**

My program encrypts and decrypts the password and unique id of the user already for double security.

I want everything to be as secure as possible. I started object orientated Python not very long ago, so please feel free to be as harsh as possible.

I'm making this unprofessionally, but it will reach production!

**Information**

- I'm using MySQL for the database, Python 3.7 for the scripting, and Flask for sessions.

  ```
           # Imports 
           from passlib.context import CryptContext 
           import mysql.connector 
           import json 
           from pprint import pprint
           # Config file loaded as a json 
           with open("database_connect.json") as config:
               config = json.load(config)
               config = config[0]
               try: 
           # Json is argued as a kwarg
                   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
                   cursor = cnx.cursor()
           # Query is made 
                   cursor.execute("SELECT first,id,pwd,uid FROM user")
                   args = cursor.fetchone() 
           # Any integer queries have the string function mapped to them
                   args = tuple(map(lambda i: str(i), args))
               except:
                   print("Connection error!")
               finally:
                   cnx.close()
           # Passlib encryption method 
           passlib_context = CryptContext(
                   schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
                   default="pbkdf2_sha256",
                   pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=300000)
           # Base class for all users 
           class default:
               priviliges = {
               "Ban": False, 
               "Kick": False, 
               "Broadcast": False, 
               "Iplookup": False }
           # Instantiating the default class 
               def __init__(self, name, uniqueid, pwd, usernameid):
                   self.name = name 
                   self.__pwd = passlib_context.hash(pwd)
                   self.__uniqueid = passlib_context.hash(uniqueid)
                   self.usernameid = usernameid
           # Encryption method for users 
               def encrypt_method(self):
                   encrypt_data = [self.__pwd, self.__uniqueid]
                   return encrypt_data 
           class decrypt(): 
           # Instantiating the decryption class 
               def __init__(self, attempted_pwd, hashpwd): 
                   self.__attempted_pwd = attempted_pwd
                   self.__hashpwd = hashpwd 
           # Decryption method for decryption class 
               def decrypt_method(self):
                   decrypt_data = passlib_context.verify(self.__attempted_pwd, self.__hashpwd) 
                   if decrypt_data is False:
                       allow_login = False
                   elif decrypt_data is True:
                       allow_login = True
                   return allow_login 
           # Information fetched from the database in tuple form, used as an argument 
           user = default(*args)
           # Attempt corresponds to user input. The first argument is the attempted password.
           attempt = decrypt("",user.encrypt_method()[0])
           print(attempt.decrypt_method())
  ```

Comment: Never use decryptable passwords. The stored password should ALWAYS be a one way HASH function. To validate that input password is equal to stored hash, hash the input with the same function.

Comment: What ege said. You can read about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) and the various linked articles. Also browse https://security.stackexchange.com/ and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ You don't need to become a security expert, or learn how to write crypto code (which is a task that should only be done by experts), but you do need to learn about the various issues, and what are the right tools to deal with the various tasks.